# what's the name of this font in the image? 555

Tags: font-identification

see the image and name the font in the image
specifically box type font 
[image]

Comment: Hi venky. We have some [requirements](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2366) for font identification questions, please take a look and edit your question to include that information.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like [Helvetica Condensed Black](https://www.fonts.com/font/linotype/helvetica) to me:

[image: Screenshot of Helvetica Condensed Black]

Answer (score -1):

Its swiss 921 font (anchoring ye kadhu paata kuda)
[image]

Comment: Do you also have a link of a font foundry where this font can be obtained? Thanks!